# Will the Atheros AR9002U WiFi chipset work out of box with Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: networking

I'm trying to find one locally today and would like to avoid having to troubleshoot to get it working.

Comment: Two down votes within seconds, but someone up votes the question with the person right above me who can't get his wifi card to work due to chipset issues lol...what a joke.

Comment: You're probably being downvoted because your post looks quite a bit like spam. We get questions pretty often that are "something something problem. <link>." that goes to some seller or unrelated site. I'm pretty confident now that you've actually interacted that you're not a spammer, but you can see how it might appear that way at first.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Seth. That makes sense now that you explain it like that. I went ahead and removed the link. It was kind of a long shot to expect someone to go shopping for a WiFi adapter me anyways.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because shopping quwstions are off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Wikidevi, the Atheros AR9002U chipset is used in the TP-Link TL-WN722N. https://wikidevi.com/wiki/TP-LINK_TL-WN722N This device uses the driver *ath9k_htc* which is built in to all recent Ubuntu versions including 18.04. The needed firmware is already included in the package *linux-firmware*.

Please use caution. The device TL-WN722N has been produced in several versions:

> *Version 1.10 has been seen printed on the box but is still the same chipset. "2052500328" and "REV: 1.1" is silkscreened on the board (PCB
>   Version 1.1)
>
> *Product Version 1.10 (on the box) with PCB Version 1.2 has been seen but is still the same chipset (minor layout differences vs. PCB
>   Version 1.1)
>
> *Version 2.x is using Realtek RTL8188EUS chip. See TP-LINK TL-WN722N v2.
>
> *Version 3.x is using Realtek RTL8188EUS chip. It is a rebadged v2.

Versions 2.x and 3.x wiill require that a driver be downloaded and compiled from source code.

Versions 1.1 and version 1,2 will work out of the box in Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [**kernel.org** page](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/ath9k_htc), the **ath9k_htc** driver provides hardware support for Atheros AR9001 and AR9002 family hardware.

On the webpage you will find more details about supported and unsupported features, as well as downloadlinks and configuration. The driver is a default driver in Ubuntu 18.04.